# Is there a difference between (int)NullableInt and NullableInt.Value?

Tags: c#

```
class Object
{
    public int? NullableInt { get; set; }
}
```

What is the difference (if any) between this:

```
int MyInt = Object.NullableInt.Value;
```

and this:

```
int MyInt = (int)Object.NullableInt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the answer is explicitly **no there is no difference**, as evidenced by the framework [source code for `Nullable<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/a7bd3242bd7732dec4aebb21fbc0f6de61c2545e/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs#L84).

```
public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value) {
    return value.Value;
}
```

`explicit operator T(Nullable<T>)` is the method used by `(int)NullableInt`, and as you can see in the source, it simply returns `.Value`.

Comment: Ah. Very good. Thank you for the investigation and pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in both cases you will get a `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message "Nullable object must have a value" in case `Object.NullableInt` is `null`. So the answer to your question is: "In theory, perhaps. But in practice, probably not".

By the way, if you want to fallback to the numerical value 0 in case when `Object.NullableInt` is `null`, you could use the expression `Object.NullableInt ?? 0`.